# A man tests high for telekinetic power, but flunks out of training. Turns out his power is different

Tags: story-identification, telekinesis

A book I read as a teenager - probably eighties - about a man (or boy?) who tests very high for potential telekinetic power.  He goes to the academy for training but, no matter how much effort he expends, he cannot make the smallest object move.

He flunks out and later, with the help of a friend, discovers that he can move objects "up"; that is, into some other "place" or dimension.  They simply disappear and he can bring them back anytime he wants, wherever he is.

The rest of the book is about him operating outside the tyranny of the academy and his flight/fight from them.  I seem to recall a space station may have been involved at one point.

Comment: I remember this story.  The protagonist had 3 or 4 similar people who tested positive for telekinesis.  The US govt put all of the positives onboard a space station with a throne that would magnify their power a thousandfold.  So the TKs took over the world.  The protagonist was given brain surgery so he wouldn't be a threat to the TKs.  But he learned how to "retrieve" things with his power, and went up to the space station and overthrew the TKs.

Comment: Sounds terrific - But can you recall the author or title, which would be the helpful part, please? :)

Answer (score 2):

This may be - may be - Cathy Livoni's 'Element of Time' from 1983. The hero has some unique power and he does flunk out of some kind of school, but that is all I can remember.

Comment: Could you add some details, maybe by looking them up online?

Comment: Plot summary available at https://www.kirkusreviews.com/book-reviews/cathy-livoni/element-of-time/